# Admob Ad's not appearing on the Amazon Store App's

Tags: android, admob, kindle-fire

I released my Android Apps on the Amazon App Store, I assumed the Admob Ad's would work fine on the Kindle Devices, but my impressions haven't changed in weeks.. So they aren't appearing.

I can't test as I don't have an Amazon Kindle Fire. :/

Can someone tell me if I need to implement Ad's differently for the Amazon App Store?

Comment: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=11680&#11680

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I actually I got a friend to test the apps, and no ads appear for it, I'll try the Kindle Emulator.

Why did I not consider the Kindle Emulator :) !! Wasn't aware there was one.

Thanks for the help